# How can I fill in the ageLabel automatically when filling in the DOB (date of birth) field and pressing calculate

Tags: ios, swift

When I run this program and fill in the DOB field with my date of birth it does not populate to the "ageLabel" as it should. But it will print out when I include the print statement. If I don't include print statement I get the warning:

> "Initialization of immutable value 'ageLabel' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it"

What am I missing?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var DOB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var DOR: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentDate: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let textInput = DOB.text
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/YYYY"
        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: textInput!)
        let currentDate = Date()
        let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
        let ageLabel = gregorian.components([.month, .year], from: startDate!, to: currentDate)

        print (ageLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outlet named `ageLabel` which appears to the the label you wish to update.

In your `calculateButton` method, you have a local variable named `ageLabel` which is actually a `DateComponents` result that you don't use.

You make no attempt to update the actual label with the calculated age.

You are also using `NSCalendar` instead of `Calendar`. And your date format mistakenly uses `YYYY` instead of `yyyy` for the year.

You also assume the user actually enters a string in the very specific format of month slash year. If the user enters anything else your app will crash.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let textInput = DOB.text!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/yyyy"
    if let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: textInput) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let ageComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: startDate, to: currentDate)
        ageLabel.text = "\(ageComponents.year!)"
    } else {
        ageLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

I just show the age in years. You can also show the months if you want.

Better yet, use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to show the age.